# smtp clients `SendAsync()` method

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, smtpclient

```
 Protected Sub btnLocalSubmit_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnLocalSubmit.Click

            Dim logic = New connections
            logic.emailsToSend(User.Identity.Name, getURL, reportedBy)
            SendAsync()
            Response.Redirect(getRedirectionPath, False)
        Catch ex As Exception
            Response.Write(ex.Message)
        Finally
            _con.Close()
            _con.Dispose()
            _sqlComm.Dispose()

        End Try
    End Sub

    Sub SendAsync()

        Dim _con As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("CitizenJDBConnectionString").ConnectionString)
        Dim _sqlDataAdapter As New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM EmailSender", _con)
        Dim _table As New System.Data.DataTable

        Try
            _con.Open()
            _sqlDataAdapter.Fill(_table)
            _con.Close()

            For i As Integer = 0 To _table.Rows.Count - 1


                Dim AppPath As String = Request.PhysicalApplicationPath

                Dim sr As New StreamReader(AppPath & "EmailTemplates/NewReport.txt")
                Dim message As New MailMessage()

                message.IsBodyHtml = True

                message.From = New MailAddress("admin@xxxx.com")

                message.To.Add(New MailAddress(_table.Rows(i).Item(1)))


                message.Subject = "New User registration !"

                message.Body = sr.ReadToEnd()

                sr.Close()

                message.Body = message.Body.Replace("<%ReporterName%>", _table.Rows(i).Item(3))

                message.Body = message.Body.Replace("<%ReportURL%>", _table.Rows(i).Item(2))

                Dim client As New SmtpClient()
                client.Host = "smtp.xxxxx.com"
                'smtp.gmail.com
                client.Port = 25
                client.UseDefaultCredentials = True
                client.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential("admin@xxxx.com", "123456")
                'client.EnableSsl = True
                Dim userState As Object = message

                'wire up the event for when the Async send is completed
                AddHandler client.SendCompleted, AddressOf SmtpClient_OnCompleted

                client.SendAsync(message, userState)

            Next

        Catch ex As Exception
            Response.Write(ex.Message)
        End Try


    End Sub 'SendAsync

    Public Sub SmtpClient_OnCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As AsyncCompletedEventArgs)
        'Get the Original MailMessage object
        Dim message As MailMessage = CType(e.UserState, MailMessage)

        'write out the subject
        Dim subject As String = message.Subject

        If e.Cancelled Then
            Console.WriteLine("Send canceled for mail with subject [{0}].", subject)
        End If
        If Not (e.Error Is Nothing) Then
            Console.WriteLine("Error {1} occurred when sending mail [{0}] ", subject, e.Error.ToString())
        Else
            Console.WriteLine("Message [{0}] sent.", subject)
        End If
    End Sub 'SmtpClient_OnCompleted
```

I am using the smtp clients `SendAsync()` function to send out emails asynchronously...but this function does not work ...why?? i do not get any email..when i send it Synchronously...i get the emails, this means my settings are correct...so what is wrong with the `SendAsync()` method??

Comment: Have you tried sending Synchronously, and checking for an error?

Comment: It looks like you are using `SendAsync()` correctly (per my [suggestion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9748542/how-to-use-threading)). A few things come to mind: - How many emails are you sending? perhaps the remote host is denying/throttling the connections because they are coming too rapidly. - Set Visual Studio to break on all exceptions (Debug -> Exceptions) to see if a `SmtpException` is thrown on another thread. - Are you getting any information from the callback? It is supposed to contain an error message (and your code looks like it came straight from MSDN so it should be correct)

Comment: You should attach to the [`SendCompleted`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.sendcompleted.aspx) event and see was the exception returned to you there is.

Comment: as of now i am sending only 3 emails...i cannot debug because i am behind a proxy server (my college uses one) so mails do not get sent as there is no option to set proxy settings with smtp...so i deploy the project and try sending mails to check it.

Comment: i have tried Response.Write(ex.message) and i got "failure Sending mail"

Comment: @TimMedora I added `Async="true"` in the page directive and now it works fine...but it waits for a long time and sends the email then refreshes the page...i mean using `Async="true"` get it working but like Synchronous mail.

Comment: @TimMedora [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9756936/can-anyone-explain-this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9756936/can-anyone-explain-this)

Comment: @TimMedora this [article](http://blog.jdconley.com/2009/01/fire-and-forget-email-webservices-and.html) helped me solve the problem ...Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do this all the time, and after years of doing this I suggest a (2) fold solution to your problem:

1. Refactor the *actual* sending email code (System.Net stuff) into a WCF service or separate .dll (I prefer the service).
2. Continue to use your asynchronous delegate call from your ASP.NET page but do so in a 'fire-and-forget' manner where you do not wire up any callbacks.

You might say you need to know if something went wrong with sending the email. Let the WCF service that sends the emails handle this. Do any logging in the service. After all that's all you were really doing anyways was logging. If you need to get fancier with a workflow if the email fails, there are ways that your ASP.NET can be flagged, but I think you will find that once the service to send the emails is stable, you will have very few problems.

In fact I have been doing this exact method for years using a service called by ASP.NET to send emails and have sent 10 of thousands of differing emails and never had any problem with this fire-and-forget design.

And lastly, setting the page `Async=True` makes the page act overall *synchronously* in the end by blocking the main thread until all asynchronous process are completed. This can make the pages very slow to load and is typically not desired.